# Find specific results from a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, text

Suppose you were reading a text file, with Javascript and jQuery and suppose the server-side guy was unwilling to give you say xml or JSON, and you want to parse the thing once to get relevant text that you will use later in an autocomplete, like so:

Text file (assume there are many similar listings and there are different DATABASES):

```
QUERY:1
DATABASE:geoquery
NL:What are the capitals of the states that border the most populated states?
SQL:something
DR:
root(ROOT-0, What-1)
cop(What-1, are-2)
det(capitals-4, the-3)
nsubj(What-1, capitals-4)
det(states-7, the-6)
prep_of(capitals-4, states-7)
nsubj(border-9, states-7)
rcmod(states-7, border-9)
det(states-13, the-10)
advmod(populated-12, most-11)
amod(states-13, populated-12)
dobj(border-9, states-13)

QUERY:2
DATABASE:geoquery
NL:What are the capitals of states bordering New York?
SQL:SELECT state.Capital FROM state JOIN border_info ON state.State_Name        
DR:
root(ROOT-0, What-1)
cop(What-1, are-2)
det(capitals-4, the-3)
nsubj(What-1, capitals-4)
prep_of(capitals-4, states-6)
partmod(states-6, bordering-7)
nn(York-9, New-8)
dobj(bordering-7, York-9)
```

I can use a regex to peel off say all NL: for example, but I need to first pare the file down so only specific NL's associated with a DATABASE get read. So read the file once getting all matches for a specific database that the user selects from a select, then make an array of NL from that list to be the source of an autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('inputQueryExamples.txt',function(data){

            // need code here to read text file first and limit results 

            var queryString = data;
            var cleanString = "";
            cleanString = queryString.match(/^NL.*/gm);
            console.log(cleanString);      
            $('#what').html(cleanString);

            var nlString = cleanString.map(function(el) {return el.replace('NL:','');});




            $('#query-list').autocomplete({
                source:nlString
            });

        });//end get

     });
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Suppose you do this properly and get the server guy to filter data for you and present it in a usable form?

Comment: Tell your server side guy he is an absolute jerk. I'm actually completely serious, because if this is for a business, client and server need to be communicating efficiently and without a lot of weird processing from the client. Also, why are SQL queries being fed back to the client?

Comment: To answer you question, we are translating natural language into SQL.  This typically leads to several possible SQL queries, usually the first translation is the best, but not always. So they want to see all the translations so the "correct" one can be chosen to execute.

Answer (score 0):

**Using regex for this is like using ducktape to patch up a severed limb.**

Any way,

*By the looks of it*, you want to get all of the NL('s) when they come from a particular database.

You would need to do a multiline regex match, with a positive lookbehind for the database name, then you'd simply match anything after NL, stopping at the next newline.

**Example:**

`(?<=DATABASE:geoquery).*?(?<=NL:)(.*?)(?=[\r\n])`

**Online demo:**

[Regex101 Example](http://regex101.com/r/wZ1tM8)